# PostgreSQL - Spiting table into two (current and history)

Tags: postgresql-15

I am looking at a legacy application that manages objects stored in a PostgreSQL database.

Each object has multiple property sets that are stored as JSONB objects.
Each of those property sets describes a different aspect of the object (can be from 1 to 10 such property sets per object).

In relation to that, different departments are usually only concerned about a couple of such property sets (aspects) so the number of property sets vary depending on who is getting involved during the lifecycle of each object.

Every time something changes in a property set by the front end application (which is beyond my control) it gets pushed back into the DB as a new JSON document.

At the moment, the table (for argument's sake) is structured as follows:

```
TABLE x (
  object_id INTEGER,
  aspect_id INTEGER,
  doc_ts TIMESTAMP,
  doc JOSNB,
  PRIMARY KEY (object_id, aspect_id, doc_ts)
)
```

The data input is handled by a procedure, which stores a copy of the document into a table, and looks as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ingest.generic_object(IN in_object_id integer, IN in_aspect_id integer, IN in_doc_ts TIMESTAMP,  IN in_doc JSONB DEFAULT NULL::JSONB)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO ingest.x ( object_id, aspect_id, doc_ts, doc) 
      VALUES (in_object_id, in_aspect_id, in_doc_ts, in_doc)
      ;
  END;
$procedure$;
```

Now let's move to the issue I am trying to resolve.
This table keeps growing over time, and can get really big, really quickly.
The housekeeping process keeps ONLY one record for each object_id and aspect_id combination (i.e. just the one with the most recent doc_ts value) takes too long to run.

I am thinking of splitting the data into two tables. Like:

```
TABLE ingest.x (
  object_id INTEGER,
  aspect_id INTEGER,
  doc_ts TIMESTAMPZ,
  doc JOSNB,
  PRIMARY KEY (object_id, aspect_id, doc_ts)
);

TABLE ingest.x_history (
  object_id INTEGER,
  aspect_id INTEGER,
  doc_ts TIMESTAMP,
  doc JOSNB,
  PRIMARY KEY (object_id, aspect_id, doc_ts)
);
```

And then change the ingestion function to something that looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ingest.generic_object(IN in_object_id integer, IN in_aspect_id integer, IN in_doc_ts TIMESTAMP, IN in_doc JSONB DEFAULT NULL::JSONB)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
  BEGIN
      WITH 
        dd AS (
          DELETE FROM ingest.x
          WHERE object_id= in_object_id
            AND aspect_id = in_aspect_id
          RETURNING *
        ), 
        di AS (
          INSERT INTO ingest.x_history ( object_id, aspect_id, doc_ts, doc) 
          SELECT object_id, aspect_id, doc_ts, doc FROM dd            
        )
      INSERT INTO ingest.x ( object_id, aspect_id, doc_ts, doc) 
      VALUES (in_object_id, in_aspect_id, in_doc_ts, in_doc)
      ;
  END;
$procedure$;
```

This would allow me to simplify the housekeeping process SIGNIFICANTLY, down to a:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE ingest.x_history;
```

My questions are as follows:

1. Considering the change above, will AUTOVACUUM lead to any reuse of the space taken by the deleted records in `ingest.x`?
2. Which table parameters for `ingest.x` should I tweak to allow me to improve reuse of the space freed by the deleted records? - Assuming that the answer to 1 is YES.
   I have FILL FACTOR along with more targeted AUTOVACUUM thresholds in mind.
3. Can you see an alternative approach into achieving an easier and effective housekeeping process?

Note:

- This is all running on PostgreSQL v15
- Document records can be written up tens of times during the creation phase - first few days. Then once every couple of days / weeks during the review period. Changes can happen after that, but are very infrequent.
- The raw data can get old really quickly, which is why TRUNCATING the history is not an issue.

Edit 1: The JSON documents range between 100kb to 2MB. I believe that those are directed to TOAST. Furthermore, the DB is on a ZFS filesystem and as such PostgreSQL compression is turned off, taking advantage of the ZFS compression.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - 1. Considering the change above, will AUTOVACUUM lead to any reuse of the space taken by the deleted records in ingest.x?

Yes, it will - that's what AUTOVACUUM is for - stopping table bloat!

> - 2. Which table parameters for ingest.x should I tweak to allow me to improve reuse of the space freed by the deleted records?

"Tweaking" various table parameters depends on **your own** usage, **your own** rates of table `INSERT`, `UPDDATE` and `DELETE`, the size of the records. The `fillfactor` is another parameter that can influence the process. Unless you have a more specific question about this, it's difficult to give a definitive answer.

This is an entire science in itself - in the Storage Parameters section of the [`CREATE TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) part of the manual, there are 17 parameters that start with `autovacuum_...` and two more starting with `vacuum_...`.

> - 3. Can you see an alternative approach into achieving an easier and effective housekeeping process?

The answer to any problem in computer science normally is "It depends!"

History tables are the "classic" solution to this problem and you can, of course as you say, `TRUNCATE` them (or put them into "cold storage" of some sort). You might also wish to consider `PARTITION`ing your tables - you'll have to read up about that and see does it suit your particular use case.

Apart from the Fine Manual, you could also read [this](https://edu.postgrespro.com/postgresql_internals-14_en.pdf) - an eBook from Postgrespro - heavy hitters in the PostgreSQL world which has an entire chapter on `AUTOVACUUM`, [here](https://www.interdb.jp/pg/) (an eBook from Japan - a bit older) might also be worth a look. Neither eBook deals with partitioning though - the FM and your favourite search engine ought to do the trick there. The related concept of [freezing](https://pganalyze.com/docs/vacuum-advisor/what-is-freezing) is also dealt with in the eBooks - again the Postgrespro book has an entire chapter!

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: You covered me on the 1st question.
Question 2 really depends on the use patterns. However, your answer reassures me that focusing on fill_factor and autovacuum settings is likely to reduce future bloat. 
On question 3, I will look at the eBook links you shared, thanks.